# Pyunit setUpClass not running

Tags: python, unit-testing

Based on the documentation for `PyUnit`, I would expect the following code to run the test `test_simple` after calling `setUpClass`. However it doesn't seem to do that, I put a print statement inside `setUpClass` to verify this.

```
import unittest

class TestData(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_simple(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print "in setupUpClass"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

From

http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html

> setUpClass()
>
> A class method called before tests in an individual class run. setUpClass 
>   is called with the class as the only argument and must be decorated as a classmethod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me. The documentation also mentions this was only added in Python 2.7 (3.2 for the 3.x releases). Do you have Python 2.7/3.2?

Comment: yup, was a version thing. thought it was running 2.7, was 2.6. oops